# AngularJS Ionic $q.all not executing inside Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this problem using $cordovaCalendar plugin. I can use this $cordovaCalendar plugin successfully to add events to the native calendar of my smartphone, and it works for me, yes! The problem is now, that I want to, when rendering a view, to check if such event E has been added to the native calendar.

I found this code online and tried to implement it. It works on addEvent, but in getEvents it does not because the $q.all is not executing, and I need the result of each promise in order to make the button in the view be depending if that event was added already or was not added.

Here is the code:

Service:

```
(function() {

   'use strict';

   angular
      .module('app.services')
      .factory('Events', EventsFunction);

   function EventsFunction($q, $cordovaCalendar) {
      var incrementDate = function(date, amount) {
         var tmpDate = new Date(date);
         tmpDate.setDate(tmpDate.getDate() + amount);
         tmpDate.setHours(13);
         tmpDate.setMinutes(0);
         tmpDate.setSeconds(0);
         tmpDate.setMilliseconds(0);

         return tmpDate;
      };

      var incrementHour = function(date, amount) {
         var tmpDate = new Date(date);
         tmpDate.setHours(tmpDate.getHours() + amount);

         return tmpDate;
      };

      var getEvents = function(events) {

         var deferred = $q.defer();
         var promises = [];

         events.forEach(function(event) {

            promises.push($cordovaCalendar.findEvent({
               title: event.title,
               startDate: event.start_time
            }));
         });

         $q.all([promises]).then(function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

               events[i].status = results[i].length === 1;
               console.log(events[i]);
            }

            deferred.resolve(events);

         });

         return deferred.promise;
      };

      var addEvent = function(event) {

         console.log(event);

         var deferred = $q.defer();

         $cordovaCalendar.createEvent({
            title: event.title,
            notes: event.ent_name,
            startDate: event.start_time,
            endDate: event.start_time

         }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('success');
            console.dir(result);
            deferred.resolve(1);

         }, function(err) {
            console.log('error');
            console.dir(err);
            deferred.resolve(0);
         });

         return deferred.promise;

      };

      return {
         get: getEvents,
         add: addEvent
      };

   }

})();
```

Controller:

```
  {
       $http({
          method: 'GET',
          skipAuthorization: true, //es necesario enviar el token url: '', headers: ... })
          .success(function (data) {


  $scope.posts = data.message;
             Events.get($scope.posts).then(function(events) {
                 console.log("events", events); 
                  $scope.events = events;
               });
               console.log($scope.events);

            });

        $scope.addEventToCalendar = function(event) {
           //console.log("In event add");
           //Events.add(event);
        }

        }
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-clear button-small button-royal button-block" ng-if="!post.status" ng-click="addEventToCalendar(post)"><b>Add to Calendar</b></button>
<p ng-if="post.status">This event is added to your calendar already!</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but the line `$q.all([promises]).then(function(results) {` should just be `$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {` - i.e. `promises` is already an array, so there is no need to wrap it in `[]`.

Comment: I tried this and this it hasn't been successful. I tried many things but it seems that the $q.all(promises) is not being called at all; but, even if it is called, it is not invoking $.all(...).